# import laz or las point clouds to revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit

Hi is anybody knows how to convert **laz** files to **rcp or rcs** ?

what i need is to import a **laz** file into **Revit** and my goal is to put the model into a forge viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LAZ` file is the compressed flavour of a `LAS` point cloud.

You can uncompress it using standard compression and decompression libraries.

Once uncompressed, you have a [Log ASCII Standard or `LAS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_ASCII_Standard) file, used in geophysical logging.

You can read the contents of that yourself, e.g., using this [open source Python LAS reader](https://github.com/joferkington/las-reader).

Here is another open source [LAS reader package](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/las).

The file format is documented on the [Canadian Well Logging Society web page](http://www.cwls.org/las).

For further suggestions, please check out the Civil 3D discussion forum thread on the [LAZ LiDAR file format](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/civil-3d-forum/laz-lidar-file-format/td-p/5026024).

I hope this helps.

Cheers, Jeremy.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, what i did is importing the **LAZ** into **ReCap** and re-saving it in **RCS** . hey Jeremy just another question...i saw your forge plugin  (roomedit3v3) in a youtube video, how you did it? and my main question is, can i make something similar in **Inventor**? without using **Ilogic** i accept all advices

Comment: dear saif, yes, something similar to the Revit room editor can be done in Inventor as well. it is really very simple. look at my other round-trip samples connecting desktop and cloud, e.g., https://github.com/jeremytammik/RoomEditorApp and https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud